# Inserting a stored procedure into a temp table, temp table returns empty

Tags: sql-server, loops, insert, temp

For reasons outside of my control, I have to query certain procedures one facility ID at a time, which means I need to loop through all facilities and inject into a temp table to be able to utilize the data efficiently.

I have utilized this loop many times and have never had an issue. For some reason with this particular query, the temp table is returning empty and I cannot figure out why.

The stored procedure executes perfectly on its own and the entire query runs without throwing any errors. However when I select * #HistoricalRentalActivity I get a blank table (but correct headers)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#HistoricalRentalActivity') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #HistoricalRentalActivity

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#rowsiteHistoricalRentalActivity') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #rowsiteHistoricalRentalActivity

SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY siteid) AS rownum, siteid 
INTO #rowsiteHistoricalRentalActivity 
FROM dbo.sites

CREATE TABLE #HistoricalRentalActivity
(
        SiteID INT,
        iSortOrder INT,
        sDescActivity VARCHAR (200),
        dcM1 MONEY,
        dcM2 MONEY,
        dcM3 MONEY,
        dcM4 MONEY,
        dcM5 MONEY,
        dcM6 MONEY,
        dcM7 MONEY,
        dcM8 MONEY,
        dcM9 MONEY,
        dcM10 MONEY,
        dcM11 MONEY,
        dcM12 MONEY,
        dcM13 MONEY,
        dcM14 MONEY,
        dc3MonthAvg MONEY
)


DECLARE @enddate datetime
SET @enddate = DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))

DECLARE @maxrow INT
SET @maxrow = (SELECT COUNT(siteid) FROM #HistoricalRentalActivity)

DECLARE @row INT
SET @row = 1

WHILE(@row <= @maxrow)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @siteidrow INT
    SET @siteidrow = (SELECT siteid FROM #rowsiteHistoricalRentalActivity WHERE rownum = @row)

    INSERT INTO #HistoricalRentalActivity (SiteID, iSortOrder, sDescActivity,
        dcM1, dcM2, dcM3, dcM4, dcM5, dcM6, dcM7, 
        dcM8, dcM9, dcM10, dcM11, dcM12, dcM13, dcM14, 
        dc3MonthAvg)
       EXEC dbo.spRptMgmtHistorytb
                @SiteID = @siteidrow,
                @dEnd = @enddate

    SET @row = @row + 1
END
```

I'm at a loss, hoping someone else has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `maxRow` needs to get a count from `#rowSiteHistoricalRentalActivity` and not the table you just created.

Comment: Oof, that was it. Staring at this too long I guess. Probably would help if I differentiated the names more also. Thanks!